# Magento 2 Enterprise : Get Coupon code Expiration Date

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, magento-2.2.5, coupon, magento2-enterprise, magento-enterprise-2

I am using Magento 2.2.5 Enterprise Edition. I'm created cart price rule from admin. Now I want to display coupon expiration date in front-end but in enterprise edition start/end date is saving by Scheduled Changes. How can I get start/end date of coupon code in enterprise edition?

Comment: where you want to get start /end date of coupon code.

Comment: I want to display all coupon codes on cart page with expiration date.I am getting all these information in community edition but can't get expiration date in enterprise edition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use API call to get coupon code and expiration date:

```
$token = 'your api token';
$searchCriteria = '{
     "search_criteria": {
         "filter_groups": [
             {
             "filters": [
                 {
                     "field": "rule_id",
                     "value": "190", //rule_id please update the value accordingly
                     "condition_type": "like"
                 }
             ]
            }
         ],
         "current_page": 1,
         "page_size": 100,
         "sort_orders": [
         ]
     }
 }';

 $searchCriteriaString = http_build_query(json_decode($searchCriteria));

 $url = 'http://yourdomain.com/rest/V1/coupons/search?'. $searchCriteriaString;
 $ch = curl_init($url);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token));

 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 $obj = json_decode($result, true);

 foreach($obj["items"] as $item) {
     echo 'Coupon Code: ' . $item['code'] . ', expiration date: ' . $item['expiration_date']. "\n";
 }
 echo "\n\n";
```

Results:

```
Coupon Code: QVN-ASK, expiration date: 2020-03-19 00:00:00
Coupon Code: TJW-N46, expiration date: 2020-03-19 00:00:00
Coupon Code: LZ1-VWN, expiration date: 2020-03-19 00:00:00
Coupon Code: 90A-KDU, expiration date: 2020-03-19 00:00:00
Coupon Code: 36X-0ZS, expiration date: 2020-03-19 00:00:00
```

You can call this API in your Block and show them in your frontend view.